# Regex with nested group and dot causes wacky matching

Tags: regex, python-2.7, notepad++, regex-group

I cannot understand why the following regex and text yield their results. I am using the regex find function in notepad++ with no Wrap_around and no matching newline. The regex:

```
name ="[\w]+\.((?:[\w]*\.?)+)" p
```

when applied to the text:

> name ="data.messageHeader.msg_time_tag.$date" pzb
>
> this is line 2

The entire text ends up highlighted, which should be impossible, since the regex should not be able to match the dollar sign or the newline/carriage return.

I have also tried applying the regex to the text with python 're'. In this case, I parsed the full file line by line. Initially, python correctly did not match the lines with dollar signs, but those lines would take a few seconds to finish even though they were only about 100 characters. By the fourth or fifth line that contained the structure of my sample, where the dot-separated words contained a '$', python froze up until I manually stopped it.

The python code used:

```
import re
def main():
    pattern = re.compile(r"name =\"\w+\.((?:\w+\.?)+)\" p")
    with open(r"filepath", "r") as f:
        i = 0
        for line in f:
            match = pattern.search(line)
            if (match):
                print('<Match: %r, groups=%r>' % (match.group(), match.groups()))
            else:
                print("line %d nomatch" % (i))
            i+=1
            match = None
            #it = pattern.finditer(f.read())
            #for element in it:
                #displaymatch(element)
    
def displaymatch(match):
    if match is None:
        return None
    print('<Match: %r, groups=%r>' % (match.group(), match.groups()))    
main()
```

Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do with that pattern? For starters, you're trying to **capture** a group of multiple **non-capturing** lookahead groups which in most cases would break a regex engine due to 'infinite' backtracking' (lookahead groups cause a separate thread to match in front of the current position while the current position remains at the same place). I'm frankly surprised that it even works without throwing an error.

Comment: @zwer reading up on lookaheads now... My goal is to capture a string of period-separated words. Specifically, I want to capture the string AFTER the first word and the first period. I will need to reference that portion of the string in my replace statement.

Comment: @zwer I should also note, that when I change the regex to 
name ="[\w]+\.((?:[\w\$]*\.?)+)" p
It works as expected, accepting strings with the dollar sign.

Comment: The issue is known, it is called *catastrophic backtracking*. The reason is also common: a `+` quantified atom is placed in a quantified group with an optional atom.  What is the expected result you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! I read up on catastrophic backtracking and I'm with you. I guess my regex WOULD produce the expected result, but it stack overflows first due to backtracking. I can't mark your comment as an answer however (or can I? I'm new)

Comment: I did not answer as I don't understand what the final outcome should look like

Comment: Given the input I posted, the regex should not match anything. I wanted a regex to match period-separated words. I find your comment to be an answer because my question was why my regex didn't work, not to give me a working regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to know why your pattern doesn't work, here's a breakdown of it:

```
name ="        - capture a literal string: `name ="`

\w+            - ... followed by one or more word characters (A-Za-z0-9_)

\.             - ... followed by a literal dot

(              - start a capturing group (following matches will be captured as a group)

    (?:        - start a non-capturing group

        \w+    - match one or more word characters (A-Za-z0-9_)
        \.?    - ... optionally followed by a literal dot

    )+         - match as many of these non-capturing groups as possible

)              - close the group, nothing is captured as there is no capturing pattern in it

" p            - followed by a literal string: `" p`
```

Think of a string like:  `name ="data.messageHeader.msg_time_tag.$date" pzb`
. If you execute the above pattern on it you'll easily capture your `name ="data.` part and that's when the fun starts - nevermind the outer group, the problem is with the inner group and the `+` qualifier behind it - it will match the first `messageHeader.`, then it will capture `msg_time_tag.` and so on until it encounters a quote character... However, since `$date` doesn't fit the inner pattern, it moves back to the previous match (backtracks) which is `messageHeader.` and tries again - only to encounter the same issue, and to backtrack again... And again... And again... Eventually shutting the engine and causing non-predictable behavior.

How will the regex engine choose to deal with this depends on the implementation - the most proper way would be to raise an infinite/catastrophic backtracking error (as the search head doesn't move despite the matches and the pattern doesn't provide a resolution), but it might just fail by capturing nothing or capturing everything...

The bottom line is - if you write proper regex pattern, the regex engine will act predictably. If not - anything goes.

Comment: The lookahead you are referring to doesn't move the cursor, like you said. But lookahead is inidcated by (?=... or (?<... . In my case, I use (?:... which indicates that the group should not be captured. But this does advance the cursor. Non-capturing groups just mean that the group can't be used in a backreference.

Comment: Ooops, I wasn't even looking at the sign after the question mark... I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

I get a long pause in Notepad++ before the text is selected, which suggests that it was caught in an infinite loop, and selecting all the text is just it's default behavior when breaking out of a loop like that.

Now, since this section `(?:[\w]*\.?)` can collapse down to nothing, and it can appear one or more times, I guess it's just repeatedly matching nothing until it finds something to match the `$`.

`name ="[\w]+\.((?:[\w$]*\.?)+)" p` seems to work correctly.

UPDATE:
This seems to handle what you ask:

```
name ="\w+\.(?:(\w+\.)*\w+)" p
```

Comment: your non-escaped dollar sign represents the end of the line, right? Then that regex should definitely match nothing. But more importantly, I DON'T want to match strings that contain a dollar sign anyway.

Comment: Characters inside `[ ]` don't need to be escaped, due to the nature of the brackets operator.

Comment: So you'd want: `name ="data.messageHeader.msg_time_tag" pzb` but not `name ="data.messageHeader.msg_time_tag.$date" pzb` ?

Comment: Oh, you're totally right! But yes, referring to my response to zwer: My goal is to capture a string of period-separated words. Specifically, I want to capture the string AFTER the first word and the first period. And while I know other regex will work. I specifically want to know why my regex does not work.

Comment: I appreciate you finding a regex that works, but I really need to know why the one I proposed doesn't work. Also, the regex needs to capture the string after the first word and the first period, excluding the space and the p.

Answer (score 0):

As Wiktor said, the regex will cause catastrophic backtracking. Specifically, it is the optional period that upon backtracking, will allow the regex to try exponential permutations of the search string. The following regex prevents catastrophic backtracking by mandating that inner words are followed by periods.

```
name ="\w+\.((\w+\.)*\w+)" p
```